# java regex match string between 2 strings

Tags: regex

I'm using Java regex and I want to match the words having 5 characters or more between 2 others words in a String chain but my regex only match the first word. Why does my regex stop the search?

example: `java regex String chain = start here christian call me water next time by facebook there too`

```
regex = (.*)(\bhere\b).?(\b[\w]{5,}\b).+(\bthere\b)
```

Comment: Do you want to say you want to get a list of three words, `['christian', 'water', 'facebook']`?

Comment: yes , its that i want...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only capture one word with `(\b[\w]{5,}\b)`. You do not capture any other words between `here` and `there`.

You can use

```java
(?:\G(?!^)|^.*\bhere)(?:\W+\w{1,4})*\W+(\w{5,})(?=.+\bthere\b)
```

See the [Java regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzTLPo/1/). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^.*\bhere)` -  end of the previous match or start of string, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `here` as a whole word
- `(?:\W+\w{1,4})*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more non-word chars and then one to four word chars (to skip these matches)
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `(\w{5,})` - Group 1: five or more word chars
- `(?=.+\bthere\b)` - a positive lookahead making sure there is a whole word `there` after one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/EqgS6U):

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text = "java regex String chain = start here christian call me water next time by facebook there too";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!^)|^.*\\bhere)(?:\\W+\\w{1,4})*\\W+(\\w{5,})(?=.+\\bthere\\b)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()) {
            res.add(m.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
// => [christian, water, facebook]
```